# How to add files to executor machines in Flink?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-flink

I'm trying to figure out ways to add some files to executors in Flink. Just like `SparkContext.addFile()` `SparkFiles.get()` in Spark, are there any possible APIs in Flink? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the documentation. The Scala API doc for ***ExecutionEnvironment*** class that serves as an entry point to Flink, has a registerCachedFile method. This can load a file from a distributed storage(for e.g hdfs) and make it available to all UDFs inside the code.

This is the link to the page in the Doc stating the same
[Flink Doc link](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/batch/#broadcast-variables) 
Check the section for **Broadcast Variables**

Comment: Thanks dude, it helps a lot :)